# Adding Mandrill SPF Record

Tags: mandrill, spf

I need to add the following to an spf record for mandrill validation:

```
include:spf.mandrillapp.com
```

Normally this is pretty straight forward but I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed with the follow situation.

Can any one offer any advice on add the above to the below spf record:

```
v=spf1 ip4: 11.111.11.111 exists:%{i}.mta.spf.xxxx.co.uk exists:%{i}.web.spf.xxxxx.co.uk -all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a stray space in there after `ip4:`, but that may have just been a question artefact. To add that include, do this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:11.111.11.111 exists:%{i}.mta.spf.xxxx.co.uk exists:%{i}.web.spf.xxxxx.co.uk include:spf.mandrillapp.com -all
```

Comment: boom, cheers synchro! Thats what happens when you get someone who knows that they are doing! Have a great day!